# Why does 4.4 support infinite Bluetooth visibility duration, but previous versions don't?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm building an app that forms a network using Bluetooth. However, Android versions less than 4.4 do not support infinite Bluetooth visibility duration. Every x amount of time (usually an hour), the app has to prompt the user to enable Bluetooth visibility. In 4.4, you can go into the Bluetooth settings and select "Never timeout" for Bluetooth visibility.

What changed between Android 4.3 and 4.4? Why didn't Android 4.3 support infinite visibility? Why does 4.4 and higher support infinite visibility now?

Comment: What do you want to achieve where the explanations of "why" and "when" and "what" help you with? It seems your question is off-topic here for multiple reasons: 1) this site is for end-users (no dev questions), 2) answers would be "primarily opinion-based" (the"why" part), and 3) it's "unclear" what issue should be solved that way.

Comment: Have you proven this in all situation, e.g. different devices, different apps, different ROM? Infinite bluetooth visibility can be considered as security issue though, so that should be the main concern. On my Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, there's no visibility setting at all; there's only "Nexus 5 is visible to nearby devices while Bluetooth settings is open".